# Munit Inaccurate Coverage

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have an Munit test suite containing two tests. Each test explores one of the two possible paths of a Mule Choice Router. Running the tests checks all the elements with green ticks to show the test has covered them, however the test coverage is reported at 60%. Why is this not 100%?

I have created a sample project in GitHub project [here](https://github.com/tomwilding/MunitCoverageTest) and this screen shot shows the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug, as you correctly reported here: https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/issues/156

Comment: Please notice this has been fix.

Checkout https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/issues/156